# PHP : Node depth

Tags: php, arrays, count

I would like to find the maximum depth of this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [children] => 
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [children] =>
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

In this case it's 3 because one of the nodes contains two children nodes.

This is the code I have been trying so far:

```
public static function nodeDepth($nodes) {
    $node_depth = array();
    foreach($nodes as $node) {
      foreach($node['children'] as $childnode) {
        $node_depth[] = nodeDepth($childnode)+1;
      }
    }
    return max($node_depth);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

    function array_depth($array) {
        $max_depth = 1;

        foreach ($array as $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $depth = array_depth($value) + 1;

                if ($depth > $max_depth) {
                    $max_depth = $depth;
                }
            }
        }        
        return $max_depth;
    }

?>
```

In you case with the child nodes, you will need to divide result by 2.

Greetz,

XpertEase